# Error: No named parameter with the name 'key'

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I am trying to do a simple constructor:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RowItem{
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;

  const RowItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
  }) : super(key : key); // <-- Here, the first key
```

, and I gеt "Error: No named parameter with the name 'key'" for the last line, first key. If you see my mistake, please, tell me about it.

Flutter is upgraded.

Comment: Your `class` does not have an `extends` clause. What does `super` do? All Dart classes implicitly extend `Object`. And the Object constructor does not accept your "key".

Comment: Yes, now I see. Sometimes I behave like blind(( Thank you! It is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key parameter from the constructor and the super call,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RowItem {
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;

  const RowItem({
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
  });
}
```

Comment: I am going to use this class in another widgets.